# C++ error no such file or directory

Tags: c++

Hey guys, I  just started learning C++ and I have this code that I have to complete but the class header is giving me this error

error: string: No such file or directory

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class Inventory
{
public:
    Inventory ();
    void Update (string item, int amount);
    void ListByName ();
    void ListByQuantity ();
private:
    vector<string> items;
};
```

Comment: the code is a mess. please "codify". also you write #include #include which is an obvious error.

Comment: ok sorry for some reason my browser is not showing the 'codify' block

Comment: This is obviously homework: "a code i have to complete" please tag it as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think your error is anything to do with namespaces.

You say you're getting *error: string: No such file or directory* which implies that the pre-compiler cannot find the STL string definition file. This is quite unlikely if you're also including vector and having no problems with that.

You should check your compilation output for clues about where it's picking header files from. Any chance you could post the full compilation output?

Comment: +1, I think you're right as to what the problem is.  I jumped to the answer too quickly.  I've deleted my answer.

Answer (score 5):

your code should probably look something more like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Inventory {
public:
    Inventory();
    void Update(const std::string& item, int amount);
    void ListByName();
    void ListByQuantity();
private:
    std::vector<std::string> items;
};
```

if   `#include <string>` is in fact your include directive, then you may be compiling the file as a c program. the compiler often determines language by the file extension. what is your file named?

Answer (score 2):

Either use `using std::string` (not recommended) or replace `string` with `std::string`.

Or, if I have misunderstood, use `#include <string>` instead of `#include "string"`.

Same goes for `vector` which is also in `std` namespace.

Comment: #include <string> is standard